# Making sense of a tensor product isomorphism

Tags: modules, tensor-products

I am having difficulty understanding why $(M \otimes P) \oplus (N \otimes P)$ does not have a higher "dimension" than $(M \oplus N) \otimes P$. The way I am viewing things, it seems like the former has a dimension of $4$ while the latter has a dimension of $3$.

Comment: $\otimes$ multiplies dimensions, it doesn't add them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are two basic "facts" about the dimension of tensor products:

> $$\dim (M\oplus N) = \dim M + \dim N$$
>   $$\dim (M\otimes N) = (\dim M)(\dim N)$$

Applying these, we can see that:
$$\dim ((M\otimes P)\oplus (N\otimes P)) = \dim (M\otimes P) + \dim (N\otimes P) = \dim M\dim P+\dim N\dim P = (\dim M+\dim N)\dim P$$
Likewise, we have that:
$$\dim((M\oplus N)\otimes P) = \dim (M\oplus N)\dim P = (\dim M+\dim N)\dim P$$
So, the dimensions are the same.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to take into account that tensor products are constructed using the free product.